# Cheat code to unlock the special cup does not work on Wii U Virtual Console

Tags: wii-u, snes, super-mario-kart

I just got Super Mario Kart for the Wii U today off of the Nintendo eShop. I found a cheat code online that you can use to automatically unlock Special Cup in time trials mode. The steps are:

1. Select 1P
2. Go to Time Trials
3. Select Mushroom Cup
4. Press the buttons LRLRLLRRA

I did all of these in order, but the problem occurs when I select the Mushroom Cup. I feel like it's not selecting it correctly or something because when I use the cheat code, it made my selection go back and forth where on the video, it didn't. I'm very confused. Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Comment: Are you sure the code is intended to be used with the Wii U? It might have just been for the original game, and not included in the port.

Comment: One of the videos I saw had a person that looked like they had a gamepad, so I think it does work on the wii u.

Comment: Can you link the video?

Comment: sidebar: Any cheatcode (provided it's not a weird "press then on player 2")  should work for the WiiU as well since the game itself should be an exact ROM of the original using the embedded Emulator.  Some of the VC games are updated (Duck Hunt and Pokemon comes to mind) but for the most part, should be whatever was the final printed version released.  That said, is that code Left Right, or R Sholder/L Shoulder?

Comment: LRLRLLRR = Left Shoulder/Right Shoulder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your note about the cup selection moving while inputting the code makes it sounds as though you are using left and right on the directional input (d-pad or analog stick). However, the code in question instead involves the use of the L and R buttons, located on the top of the controller. You should have no problem once you use those buttons to input the code instead of Left and Right.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob at retro games, so sorry if this is such a dumb problem